# Using different group by statements in DB2

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

I have a successful query which is returning some data for a user and category (the query is grouped by category and user)
which is basically showing projections for each category per user

```
select 
    user, 
    category, 
    sum(CatProjection) as CatProjection, 
    sum(CatProjection)/52 as WeekCatProjection
from projections
where user = 123
group by user, category
```

And this returns what I want/expect:

```
USER  |   CATEGORY      |   CatProjection |  WeekCatProjection   
----------------------------------------------------------------
123   |   CategoryA     |   755000        |   14519              
123   |   CategoryB     |   390000        |   7500              
123   |   CategoryC     |   281250        |   5408
```

The issue is, those results are grouped by user and category, and now I want to add two columns which are dependent on the sum of CatProjection for that user, but not grouped by category.

So for the new value TotalCatProjection, I want to add all CatProjection values for that User. I then want to user CatPercentage to divide the WeekCatProjection by TotalCatProjection.

So now I would expect these results:

```
USER  |   CATEGORY      |   CatProjection |  WeekCatProjection   |  TotalCatProjection |  CatPercentage 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
123   |   CategoryA     |   755000        |   14519              |  27427              |    52.94
123   |   CategoryB     |   390000        |   7500               |  27427              |    27.35
123   |   CategoryC     |   281250        |   5408               |  27427              |    19.72
```

How can I get these 2 new columns which are based only on the USER when my main query is grouped by user AND category?

Comment: Do you always get it for just one user? I mean do you always have the `where user = XXX` condition there?

Comment: It's in a php script where it says ```where user = {$user}```  so no there's not always one user but I'm testing these queries off of one user. It will have the where clause though

Comment: I suppose it could just be grouped by user but I'm testing on one right now

Comment: which version of DB2 do you have?

Comment: I'm currently running 7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the window functions are introduced in [DB2 7.3](https://www.itjungle.com/2016/05/10/fhg051016-story01/) you should use a subquery solution:

```
select user, 
    category, 
    CatProjection, 
    WeekCatProjection,
    TotalCatProjection,
    100 * WeekCatProjection / TotalCatProjection
from
(
    select 
        user, 
        category, 
        sum(CatProjection) as CatProjection, 
        sum(CatProjection)/52 as WeekCatProjection,
        ( 
           select sum(CatProjection) 
           from projections p2
           where p1.user = p2.user
        ) as TotalCatProjection
    from projections p1
    group by user, category 
) t
```

I avoid the `where user = XYZ` condition because then the `GROUP BY user` does not make a sense, however, you can insert it there if you want to.

Comment: Hmm, it says Token ( was not valid.

Comment: @TomN. ok, and what about the subquery solution?

Comment: It says more than one row returned. However, I got it to work using:

```(SELECT SUM(catProjection) from projections where user = 309) as TotalCatProjection```

Comment: But now I'm wondering how I can divide CatProjection by TotalCatProjection

Comment: Wait your update does work! Thank you, I missed the update you made somehow

Comment: So could I now user the aliases CatProjection/TotalCatProjection? Or will it not allow division as a column by alias?

Comment: @TomN. I have updated the solution so it avoids duplicate code to do the computation.

Comment: Absolutely perfect! Thanks so much